# SVM - running time for detecting if data is linearly separable?

Tags: svm, separation

If my understanding is correct, one way to check if a set of $m$ data points is linearly separable is to use support vector machines to find a maximum margin hyperlane for separating the data; the data is linearly separable if and only if such a hyperplane exists.

If the data consists of $m$ pairs $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_m,y_m)$, with $x_i \in \{0,1\}^n$ and $y_i \in \{0,1\}$, do we know what the worst case running time is for finding whether or not a maximum margin hyperlane exists?

Comment: [Linear SVM can be trained in sublinear time](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4359-beating-sgd-learning-svms-in-sublinear-time.pdf). The complexity of exact kernel SVM ranges from $O(n^2)$ to $O(n^3)$, depending on the strength of regularization, where $n$ is the size of your training set.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the work on SVM algorithms focuses on the soft-margin case and so isn't really applicable here.$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$

But the question of finding the existence of a linear separator can be solved instead as a linear program:
Let $X_+$ be the matrix whose rows are the positive instances (the $x_i$ with $y_i = 1$), and $X_-$ the matrix whose rows are the negatives.
Then our question is:
is there a $\beta \in \R^n$ and $b \in \R$ such that
$X_+ \beta > b$ and $X_- \beta < b$?

This is a linear feasibility problem in $n+1$ dimensions with $m$ linear constraints. Since your $X$ are binary, the LP can then be represented in $O(m n)$ bits; as an upper bound, [Karmarkar's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmarkar%27s_algorithm) then runs in
$$O(m^2 n^{5.5} \log(m n) \log(\log(m n)))$$
time.

Better bounds are certainly possible depending on the setting. For example, if the dimension $n$ is low, [Megiddo (1984)](http://theory.stanford.edu/~megiddo/pdf/lplin.pdf) gives an algorithm that takes fewer than $2^{2^{n+3}} m$ steps, or another which takes fewer than $\frac{2^{(n+1)^2}}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k!} m (\log m)^{(n+1)^2}$.

Comment: Class answer. +1